# Setup api access token, on test class level using fixtures, raises scopeMissmatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have the following fixture to setup env config properties, in conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture
def config(request):
    return LazySettings("environmentConfigs." + request.config.getoption("--environment"))
```

Then I want a class level fixture to create a login token, that will be available Only for the tests inside this test_class

```
class Test_SomeTests():
    @pytest.fixture(scope='class')
    def token(self, config):
        token = Client.login(base_url=config.base_url)
        yield token 
        pass
```

My goal is to have a fixture to load the data, the data, second is to have a access token available only for tests within a specific class, and not shared across test modules

Problem is there is error raised:

```
ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the function scoped fixture config with a class scoped request object, involved factories:
Tests\test_something.py:8:  def token(config)
conftest.py:37:  def config(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to request a `function` scope fixture (default scope when not defined) from a `class` scope fixture because `class` scope is wider. So if you are using `class` scope you are able to request fixtures with following scopes: `class, module, package, session`.

It makes sense because `class` scope fixture will be executed once during class tests execution, meanwhile `function` scope should be executed before every test function. So here is the contradiction.

To make your code work you need to change the scope of your `config` fixture to `class` or some wider scope.

If you are fine with having just one `LazySettings` initialization for whole test execution then you can use `session` scope.

[Read more about pytest fixtures' scopes](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session)